# Three Year Old Website with no traffic versus a fresh wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, traffic, asp.net-mvc

I made a price comparison engine about 3-4 years ago in asp.net mvc. Kept making changes now and then. Added a "news" and "apps" section where daily tech news and app updates are posted. At once there were two separate websites, one was for desktop and one was for mobile (http://m.mysite.com). Later I upgraded everything to MVC5 with bootstrap. So for last 8-10 months its just one website. At once I also added a wardrobe category, but later removed it. Basically tried a few things before reaching a stage to write this post.

Current status is that I add tech news and app updates on a regular basis, and add products now and then. But nothing has worked. Even the domain name choice wasn't great which I realized a year later when I discovered some big portal contained my name. That is, when some starts to type my website name, the bigger portal name comes (mine is pricepan and the other is pricepanda).

And finally, I am thinking to close my developed website in favor of wordpress website. A fresh domain, a fresh site with SEO baked right in.

But, before taking the final call, I wanted to ask you if there are any merits of sticking around with my website, or same domain with wordpress installation. To me, it seems a three old baggage which google won't consider much now even with wordpress and better SEO. Just let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things here.

1. You can build new website on a new doming and redirect (301) old one to new one and also let Google know about the change using change of address tool: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en
2. Note: WordPress is just a platform and it has nothing to do with ranking. A general website can be ranked equally. Meaning platform is not the deciding factor for SEO.
3. If your 3-year-old website may have good content or business process implemented with possibility of getting ranking then you can create a new website and use the business process and content with new UI.

**Conclusion:**
The platform doesn't guarantee ranking. You need to build good content. You can build the new website in WP as you wanted, redirect old one to new one as you may get some SEO signals like domain age etc.